# Create CSV from Dynamic Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, gridview

I have an ASP.net site that contains two list boxes. The gridview control populates according to which item is selected. The gridview control can only have 1 of 2 types of different column name structures.

I've left out the column tags on the aspx page entirely.

My C# code does not know there are columns and rows in the gridview, even though it displays on screen. The 'Save As' prompt runs and I'm able to download the CSV file, but there is no captured data.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
 "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/text";

GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
{
    //add separator
    sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
}
//append new line
sb.Append("\r\n");
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        //add separator
        sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
    }
    //append new line
    sb.Append("\r\n");
}
Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? Is it iterating over the columns and rows?

Comment: I did debug, it's not iterating over the columns and rows. Hence I think the gridview is not actually registering that the columns and rows are there.

Comment: Does the gridview display on the ASP.NET page?

Comment: what if you iterate through your datasource rather than the gridview?

Comment: The gridview does display on the ASP.net page. I didn't know it was possible to iterate through the datasource. Would it follow a similar syntax i.e. datasource1.column.count?